# How to revert to the original config files in OS X?

Tags: osx

How can I revert config files in OS X 10.8.2 to their original state? I want to discard any changes made to /etc/hosts, /etc/sshd_config, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only options I can think of are the obvious ones:

1. Time machine backup.
2. Grab them from a fresh install or install disk.